# ASP.NET MVC 3 site with one page using NT auth and the rest unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, ssl

I am creating a site for our customer service department to request password rest emails for our customers. The flow is that a customer can call CS, give them their identifying info then CS will click a button on our site to send an email to the users registered address.

To simplify things, I would like to have the CS page require that the user be internal and logged-in to our domain. But the customer should be able to hit the site without credentials. So, I would like the CS views to require NT auth but not those for the customers.

The entire site would be using SSL.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read up on the `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: Have you read up on the `[RequireHttps]` attribute, as well?

Comment: Why yes I have! It's been a while as I've been writing internal services for a couple of years. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the controllers/Actions that are restricted to your CS people you could use Authorize Attribute.  This could tie them to a specific domain group and would utilize their logged in credentials and permissions.

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\GroupName")]
```

Then the pages/controllers that don't need to be restricted or are handled through an application level login you can run them through your normal login methods.